# "master_not_discovered_exception" when trying to configure Elastic Search on remote server

Tags: configuration, remote-access, elasticsearch-7

I'm trying to configure Elastic Search on one of our remote servers. I've installed it with .msi setup file (v7.1.1) and configured the firewall for 9200 and 9300 ports.

When I set `network.publish_host` to server ip it gave me this error `the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`. Then I've made some research and set `cluster.initial_master_nodes` to my single node which named "ElasticSearchNode". Now the service is running but when i check the cluster health it says "master_not_discovered_exception".

My current yml file looks like:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: ElasticSearchNode
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: x.x.x.x
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ElasticSearchNode
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

The response when i requested /_cat/health?v

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null}],"type":"master_not_discovered_exception","reason":null},"status":503}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

From ES-7 onwards add the below config in the .yml file

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes : <IP_or_DNS_of_master_node>
```

Answer (score 4):

From ES7, it worked for me:

1. `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
2. Uncomment the `node.name` line
3. Change `network.host` to `0.0.0.0`, `discovery.seed.hosts` to `[“127.0.0.1”]`, and `cluster.initial_master_nodes` to `[“node-1”]`
4. When done, quit nano, then type `:ctrl-x,` type `yes`
5. `sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload`
6. `sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service`
7. `sudo /bin/systemctl restart elasticsearch.service`